# Left join with string function?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to left join two tables:

- One table has emails
- The other table, is a domain blacklist.

I did something like this:

```
SELECT
   CASE 
      WHEN b.domain IS NULL then "Invalid"
      ELSE "Valid"
   END as Validated
FROM Emails e
LEFT JOIN DomainBlacklist b
ON ENDS_WITH(LOWER(e.email), LOWER(b.domain))
```

But throws me an error:

"LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join."

Someone know how can I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT email, 
  IF(MAX(ENDS_WITH(LOWER(email), LOWER(domain))), 'invalid', 'valid') AS Validated
FROM `project.dataset.Emails`
CROSS JOIN `project.dataset.DomainBlacklist`
GROUP BY email
```

You can test / play with above query using dummy data as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.Emails` AS (
  SELECT email
  FROM UNNEST(['user1@abc.com','user2@abc.com','user3@uvw.com','user4@xyz.com']) AS email 
), `project.dataset.DomainBlacklist` AS (
  SELECT domain
  FROM UNNEST(['uvw.com','qwe.net']) AS domain
)
SELECT email, 
  IF(MAX(ENDS_WITH(LOWER(email), LOWER(domain))), 'invalid', 'valid') AS Validated
FROM `project.dataset.Emails`
CROSS JOIN `project.dataset.DomainBlacklist`
GROUP BY email
```

result is

```
email           Validated    
user1@abc.com   valid    
user2@abc.com   valid    
user3@uvw.com   invalid  
user4@xyz.com   valid
```

Comment: Hi! 

Your query works excellent in the test, but if I execute with real tables, the error persist :(.

Comment: My edited query is: SELECT
IF ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `Operaciones.DominioErrado` d WHERE ENDS_WITH(LOWER(r.correo), LOWER(d.dominio))) > 0, 'invalid', 'valid') AS Validated
FROM Modelo.Registrados r

Comment: The same:

"LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join."
:(

Comment: let me check this - i have not tested this with actual tables but rather with table expressions (using WITH) so that can be reason why it works with my example but not with real tables - will get back shortly

Answer (score 2):

In theory it should be possible to express this as a join with an equality; you need to strip the `@` from the email address first:

```
SELECT
   CASE 
      WHEN b.domain IS NULL then "Invalid"
      ELSE "Valid"
   END as Validated
FROM Emails e
LEFT JOIN DomainBlacklist b
ON LOWER(SPLIT(e.email, '@')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)]) = LOWER(b.domain)
```

Using sample data:

```
WITH Emails AS (
  SELECT 'elliott@example.com' AS email UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a@b.com' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'invalid_email' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'foo@bar.com'
), DomainBlacklist AS (
  SELECT 'example.com' AS domain UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bar.com'
)
SELECT
   CASE 
      WHEN b.domain IS NULL then "Invalid"
      ELSE "Valid"
   END as Validated
FROM Emails e
LEFT JOIN DomainBlacklist b
ON LOWER(SPLIT(e.email, '@')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)]) = LOWER(b.domain)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
There is any way to do this without split? Because we have domains, not subdomains, so if the email is "bla@something.example.com" the script doesn't work (or, what if the field isn't a email?)

Comment: The query just treats values that are not emails as invalid. You can use URL functions for normalization potentially; have you seen `NET.REG_DOMAIN` and others in the documentation? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'll pass that link to our analytics team :)